# Is there a way to setup AWS Active Directory for cross region failover?

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory

We're looking at AWS Active Directory but it appears to only support deployment within a single region at a time.  It does deploy a pair of instances in separate availability zones which helps but we've all seen entire regions have trouble.  Has anyone figured out a way around this...perhaps setting up AWS AD in separate regions and then connecting them somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: trying to find out whether AWS Directory Service (Enterprise) is single or multi-region - can't find it in the official docs anywhere. I take it from your post that it's single region?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options that I can think of...

1. Setup a new domain in a different region and then create a 2 way transitive forest trust between your 2 AWS AD Directory Service domains
2. Ditch the AD directory as a service and build you own AD on ec2 instances, use VPC peering connections to cross regions and have an AD server in each